# Creating combination of value list with existing key - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

So my rdd consists of data looking like:

```
(k, [v1,v2,v3...])
```

I want to create a combination of all sets of two for the value part.

So the end map should look like:

```
(k1, (v1,v2))
(k1, (v1,v3))
(k1, (v2,v3))
```

I know to get the value part, I would use something like

```
rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter(case (a,b) => a < b)
```

However, that requires the entire rdd to be passed (right?) not just the value part.  I am unsure how to arrive at my desired end, I suspect its a groupby.

Also, ultimately, I want to get to the k,v looking like

```
((k1,v1,v2),1)
```

I know how to get from what I am looking for to that, but maybe its easier to go straight there?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please format your question, get rid of the abbreviations, and [read this document](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will make your question useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Israel's answer is a incomplete, so I go a step further.

```
import itertools

a = sc.parallelize([
    (1, [1,2,3,4]),
    (2, [3,4,5,6]),
    (3, [-1,2,3,4])
  ])

def combinations(row):
  l = row[1]
  k = row[0]
  return [(k, v) for v in itertools.combinations(l, 2)]

a.map(combinations).flatMap(lambda x: x).take(3)
# [(1, (1, 2)), (1, (1, 3)), (1, (1, 4))]
```

Comment: Yeah I did have to flatmap it myself to get it into the final desired format

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools` to create the combinations. Here is a demo:

```
import itertools

k, v1, v2, v3 = 'k1 v1 v2 v3'.split()

a = (k, [v1,v2,v3])

b = itertools.combinations(a[1], 2)
data = [(k, pair) for pair in b]
```

`data` will be:

```
[('k1', ('v1', 'v2')), ('k1', ('v1', 'v3')), ('k1', ('v2', 'v3'))]
```

Comment: So within pyspark, I need to create another function to do this?  Because I dont know how to chain that.  I thought about creating a function and then importing it that would look something like that.  I didnt know if there was a native way to do it via prebuilt functions.

Comment: You can create a function that receives the k and a list of v, and returns the data as in my answer

Comment: Thanks!  Got this to work and learned I could just paste a function into pyspark!

Answer (score 0):

I have made this algorithm, but with higher numbers looks like that doesn't work or its very slow, it will run in a cluster of big data(cloudera), so i think that i have to put the function into pyspark, please give a hand if you can.

import pandas as pd
import itertools as itts

number_list = [10953, 10423, 10053]

def reducer(nums):
  def ranges(n):
    print(n)
    return range(n, -1, -1)

num_list = list(map(ranges, nums))
  return list(itts.product(*num_list))

data=pd.DataFrame(reducer(number_list))
print(data)