# Creating combination and sum of value lists with existing key - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My question is similar to the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026480/creating-combination-of-value-list-with-existing-key-pyspark), however, I have an additional field that I would like to get the sum from, that is, my RDD is as follows (I show it as a data frame)

```
+----------+----------------+----------------+
|    c1    |        c2      |      val       |
+----------+----------------+----------------+
|        t1|         [a, b] |        [11, 12]|
|        t2|     [a, b, c ] |    [13, 14, 15]|
|        t3|   [a, b, c, d] |[16, 17, 18, 19]|
+----------+----------------+----------------+
```

and I would like to get something like this:

```
        +----------+----------------+----------------+
        |    c1    |        c2      |     sum(val)   |
        +----------+----------------+----------------+
        |        t1|         [a, b] |        23      |
        |        t2|         [a, b] |        27      |
        |        t2|         [a, c] |        28      |
        |        t2|         [b, d] |        29      |
        |        t3|         [a, b] |        33      |
        |        t3|         [a, c] |        34      |
        |        t3|         [a, d] |        35      |
        |        t3|         [b, c] |        35      |
        |        t3|         [b, d] |        36      |
        |        t3|         [c, d] |        37      |
        +----------+----------------+----------------+
```

with the following code I get the first two columns

```
def combinations(row):
    l = row[1]
    k = row[0]
    m = row[2]
return [(k, v) for v in itertools.combinations(l, 2)]

a.map(combinations).flatMap(lambda x: x).take(5)
```

With this code I try to get the third column but I get more rows

```
    def combinations(row):
            l = row[1]
            k = row[0]
            m = row[2]
    return [(k, v, x) for v in itertools.combinations(l, 2) for x in map(sum, itertools.combinations(m, 2)) ]
        
a.map(combinations).flatMap(lambda x: x).take(5)
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
a = sc.parallelize([
    (1, [1,2,3,4], [11,12,13,14]),
    (2, [3,4,5,6], [15,16,17,18]),
    (3, [-1,2,3,4], [19,20,21,22])
  ])

def combinations(row):
    l = row[1]
    k = row[0]
    m = row[2]
    return [(k, v, x) for v in itertools.combinations(l, 2) for x in map(sum, itertools.combinations(m, 2))]

a.map(combinations).flatMap(lambda x: x).take(5)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lavesh. I obtain a base with 18 * 18 rows and, using your example, I would like to obtain a base with 18 rows, which are the total combinations of column 2 in "a" for each key in column 1, also I would like to obtain in a third column the sum of the elements in column 3 from "a" that correspond to the elements in each pair given by the combination of column 2.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample data and also 1 or 2 expected outputs. Also, meanwhile, you can accept the answer if it satisfies the asked question, as I can see you have changed the question using that answer, which would make my answer obsolete.

Comment: You can ignore my comment above where it says "Is it possible to share sample data and also 1 or 2 expected outputs". I should have deleted it, while writing 2nd line. Also, please check this post for handling such scenarios, where you want to change the original question to make answers irrelevant. [link] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309237/dealing-with-questions-that-are-edited-after-my-answer-has-been-accepted). I would wonder if I should spend more time on this so that you can change your question again without accepting it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to asking questions but should have learned more about Q&A. I changed the question thanks to your answer that made me think about giving more information in order to achieve a better understanding of what I want. I have accepted your answer and I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 0):

solve it as follows

```
    def combinations(row):
    l = row[1]
    k = row[0]
    m = row[2]
    return [(k, v,m[l.index(v[0])]+m[l.index(v[1])]) for v in itertools.combinations(l, 2)]

a.map(combinations).flatMap(lambda x: x).take(5)
```

Since the number of elements in the second and third column is the same, I extract the elements and add them. Thanks to Lavesh's answer, he helped me find a solution.

Comment: `l.index(v[1]) won't work if v[1] == v[0]`, it will always return the index of the first match.

Comment: That's right, however for my dataset v[0] is always different from v[1]. Thanks for the comment.